# Getting a installation error using updated Gatsby version

Tags: gatsby

I'm setting up a new Gatsby project with `npm init gatsby`

Once the installation is completed I run `npm start` and get this error:

```
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Unexpected token (5:9)

File: node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image/gatsby-browser.js:5:9

failed Re-building development bundle - 0.752s
ERROR in ./node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image/gatsby-browser.js 5:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no
loaders are configured to process this file. See
https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| export function wrapRootElement({ element }) {
>   return <LaterHydrator>{element}</LaterHydrator>
| }
| 
 @ ./.cache/api-runner-browser-plugins.js 18:10-74
 @ ./.cache/api-runner-browser.js 4:14-53
 @ ./.cache/app.js 12:0-65 29:87-33:1 37:20-29 50:0-14 116:17-26 150:6-15
29:0-33:2

develop compiled with 1 error
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "patrick-developes-homepage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "patrick-developes-homepage",
  "keywords": [
    "decentralization"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "gatsby clean && gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
}
```

Does anybody know if the `npm init gatsby` command was not being updated after the release of the gatsby ^4.1.0 version?

My solution:

I've reinstalled everything and now it's working. Perhaps, it was just a bug.

Comment: Have you tried using yarn?

Comment: I've reinstalled everything and now it's working. Perhaps it was just a bug.